# Two different implementations only for some methods of the same in class .NET (design pattern)

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have one class with many methods. I need to have two different implementations of two methods within class, but all other methods should be the same.

```
public class MyDataService: IMyDataService
{
       public void Method1() { // get data from external service } 
       public void Method2() { // get data from external service } 

       public void CommonMethodA() { // some get data} 
       public void CommonMethodB() { // some get data } 
       public void CommonMethodC() { // some get data }
        ... and other methods here 
}
```

`IMyService` is injected in `Startup`. In another layer we use these methods.

```
public class MyManager {

       public void DoComplexCalculations() {
            _myservice.CommonMethodA();

            _myservice.CommonMethodB();

            _myservice.Method1();
       }
}

public class Caculator1() {
     public void Do() { _mymanager.DoComplexCalculations(); }
}
```

However, now we have developed another application (in .net it is separate project within the same solution), it also calls `MyManager.DoComplexCalculations`.

```
public class Caculator2() {
    // we need to call the same calculations, but need different Metohd1 and Method2
    public void Do() { _mymanager.DoComplexCalculations(); }
}
```

Instead of calling `Method1` and `Method2` we need to get data form `Cache` (call `FromCacheMethod1` and call `FromCacheMethod2` ). All other methods are common and are still needed. Data are already cached before calling `MyManager.DoComplexCalculations`. What is best approach to achieve this?

1. Using Decorator pattern, but in this case we should create a lot of unneeded code, just duplicating CommonMethodX calls in decorator class. And it doesn't sound actually like Decorator.
2. Or add get from cache code inside `Mehtod1` and `Method2`, but this also doesn't sound as good pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a template or an order how methods should be called. If it is true, then chances are you can use [Template pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method). Otherwise, it is possible to use [Strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy).

According to wiki, [Template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) is:

> The template method is a method in a superclass, usually an abstract
> superclass, and **defines the skeleton of an operation in terms of a
> number of high-level steps**. These steps are themselves implemented by
> additional helper methods in the same class as the template method.
>
> The helper methods may be either abstract methods, in which case
> subclasses are required to provide concrete implementations, or hook
> methods, which have empty bodies in the superclass. Subclasses can
> (but are not required to) customize the operation by overriding the
> hook methods. The intent of the template method is to define the
> overall structure of the operation, while allowing subclasses to
> refine, or redefine, certain steps.

Let me show the example of Template pattern via C#:

```
public abstract class DataServiceBase
{
    public void DoComplexCalculations()
    {
        Method1();
        Method2();

        CommonMethodA();
        CommonMethodB();
        CommonMethodC();
    }

    public abstract void Method1();

    public abstract void Method2();

    public void CommonMethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CommonMethod A");
    }

    public void CommonMethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CommonMethod B");
    }

    public void CommonMethodC()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CommonMethod C");
    }
}
```

And these are the derived classes of DataServiceBase where you can override and customize a behaviour of `Method1()`    and `Method2()`:

```
public class MyDataService_1 : DataServiceBase
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDataService_1 Method1 ");
    }

    public override void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDataService_1 Method2");
    }
}
```

and another template:

```
public class MyDataService_2 : DataServiceBase
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDataService_2 Method1");
    }

    public override void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDataService_2 Method2");
    }
}
```

In order to call the above classes, we can create a simple factory. Simple factory is not [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and not [Abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). To be honest, there is no pattern like *simple factory*. At least, canonical book by GoF does not describe a such pattern.

```
public enum ServiceType
{
    One,
    Two
}
```

and Factory class would look like this:

```
public class DataServiceFactory
{
    private Dictionary<ServiceType, DataServiceBase> _servicesByType = 
        new Dictionary<ServiceType, DataServiceBase>()
    {
        { ServiceType.One, new MyDataService_1() },
        { ServiceType.Two, new MyDataService_2() },
    };

    public DataServiceBase GetInstanceByType(ServiceType serviceType) => 
        _servicesByType[serviceType];
}
```

Now we have a simpler interface to call the concrete implementations of `DataServiceBase` class:

```
DataServiceFactory dataServiceFactory = new DataServiceFactory();
DataServiceBase dataService_1 = dataServiceFactory.GetInstanceByType(ServiceType.One);
dataService_1.DoComplexCalculations();

Console.WriteLine();

DataServiceBase dataService_2 = dataServiceFactory.GetInstanceByType(ServiceType.Two);
dataService_2.DoComplexCalculations();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the completely different order of methods, then it is possible to use [Strategy pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy).

As wiki says about [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

> The strategy pattern (also known as the policy pattern) is a
> behavioral software design pattern that enables **selecting an
> algorithm at runtime**. Instead of implementing a single algorithm
> directly, code receives run-time instructions as to which in a family
> of algorithms to use

Let me show the example of Template pattern via C#:

```
public abstract class DataServiceStrategyBase
{
    public abstract void DoComplexCalculations();

    public abstract void Method1();

    public abstract void Method2();

    public void CommonMethodA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CommonMethod A");
    }

    public void CommonMethodB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CommonMethod B");
    }

    public void CommonMethodC()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CommonMethod C");
    }
}
```

And these are the derived classes of DataServiceBase where you can override and customize a behaviour of DoComplexCalculations(), `Method1()` and `Method2()`:

```
public class MyDataServiceStrategyOne : DataServiceStrategyBase
{
    public override void DoComplexCalculations()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoComplexCalculations MyDataServiceStrategyOne");
    }

    public override void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDataServiceStrategyOne Method1");
    }

    public override void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDataServiceStrategyOne Method1");
    }
}
```

and another template:

```
public class MyDataServiceStrategyTwo : DataServiceStrategyBase
{
    public override void DoComplexCalculations()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoComplexCalculations MyDataServiceStrategyTwo");
    }

    public override void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDataServiceStrategyTwo Method1");
    }

    public override void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyDataServiceStrategyTwo Method1");
    }
}
```

In order to call the above classes, we can create a simple factory. Simple factory is not [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and not [Abstract factory][4]. To be honest, there is no pattern like *simple factory*. At least, canonical book by GoF does not describe a such pattern.

```
public enum ServiceType
{
    One,
    Two
}
```

and Factory class would look like this:

```
public class DataServiceStrategyFactory
{
    private Dictionary<ServiceType, DataServiceStrategyBase> _servicesByType = new ()
    {
        { ServiceType.One, new MyDataServiceStrategyOne() },
        { ServiceType.Two, new MyDataServiceStrategyTwo() },
    };

    public DataServiceStrategyBase GetInstanceByType(ServiceType serviceType) =>
        _servicesByType[serviceType];
}
```

Now we have a simpler interface to call the concrete implementations of `DataServiceBase` class:

```
DataServiceStrategyFactory dataServiceStrategyFactory = new ();
DataServiceStrategyBase dataService_1 = 
    dataServiceStrategyFactory.GetInstanceByType(ServiceType.One);
dataService_1.DoComplexCalculations();

Console.WriteLine();

DataServiceStrategyBase dataService_2 = 
    dataServiceStrategyFactory.GetInstanceByType(ServiceType.Two);
dataService_2.DoComplexCalculations();
```